# dangerouslyGetParent - never giving falsy if nested

Tags: react-navigation

When using `dangerouslyGetParent`, I am never finding it to be falsy if it's used from a nested navigator. I did a small code dive and can't find it to be falsy if it is from a nested navigator. Am I wrong? Is there a chance that a nested navigator can give undefined/null from `dangerouslyGetParent`?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> Reason why the function is called dangerouslyGetParent is to warn developers against overusing it to eg. get parent of parent and other hard-to-follow patterns.

Source: https://reactnavigation.org/docs/en/navigation-key.html#usage-with-reset-navigation-actionshtml-reset

Seems to me that you're fine. The cause for concern is just ensuring that you aren't using any anti-patterns or difficult-to-read patterns.

Also:

> Be sure to always check that the call returns a valid value.

Source: https://reactnavigation.org/docs/en/navigation-prop.html#dangerouslygetparent-get-parent-navigator

which it sounds like you're doing

Historical context here: https://github.com/react-navigation/rfcs/issues/27#issuecomment-370913271

> we might want to name it something a little less inviting than `getParent()` so as to not encourage people to `getParent().getParent()` etc, which we know from building larger apps can cause frustrating bugs when screens and nav structure shuffle around

Comment: I appreciate your feedback spex! Re "be sure to always check that the call returns a valid value."  I actually removed the gaurd statements from my nested navigators because I saw it was never ever returning falsy. So this would be safe?

Comment: It's likely fine, but could crop up as a bug as your app grows and you or someone else makes a change that causes it to return an invalid value. Just something to consider as they mention it in the docs.

Comment: over in the documentation file you can notice that is not recommended to over use it, please be careful when using it.

Comment: @EmadBaqeri That's made clear in the answer above in the very first sentence along with a link to that point in the documentation.

Comment: @spex thanks for mentioning I have not seen it sorry.